# Joining two different databases with filtering beforehand in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have Users and Sessions tables. User can have many sessions, or none (if the user didn't open a session even once), while each session must have one user.

Im trying to create an output of all users and their total number of sessions in a specific time range.
Without the time range, its pretty easy (I think...):

```
User.left_outer_joins(:sessions).select('users.*, COUNT(sessions.id) AS sessions_count').group('users.id')
```

But remember I'm trying to count only sessions from a specific time range, so when I add:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:sessions).where('sessions.created_at > 2017-04-30 00:00:00').select('users.*, COUNT(sessions.id) AS sessions_count').group('users.id')
```

I can't see all users who didn't had any sessions at the given time range. How is that happening? and is there any way to make the query even more efficient?

Comment: Try `User.includes(:sessions)...`

Comment: That gives out some gigantic query... plus, and error (just changing the 'left_outer_joins' with 'includes')

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are imagining that you are left joining against a restricted set of sessions.  But what you are doing is taking a left joined data set and restricting it by sessions.    More broadly, this looks like a weird hybrid of rails methods and raw sql.  Probably should just use rails--or you can use SQL for speed if you need to, but might as well write a pure SQL method if you are going that route.